# How to using Bundle in if else

Tags: java, android, if-statement

In this code I have an if else block. In the if else I want to include a button using bundle but I have tried and I get an error. My code is below, does anyone have any ideas why I am getting the error?

```
package com.apps.visitkuningan;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class KetWisata extends Activity{
    Intent iinntteen;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.ket_wisata);
        String tampil = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
        ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wisata);
        TextView nama = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nama);
        TextView alamat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alamat);
        TextView keterangan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.keterangan);
        Button arahkan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.arahkan);
        final Bundle bundel2 = new Bundle();
        final String tampil2 = null;
        arahkan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                bundel2.putString("key", tampil2);
                iinntteen.putExtras(bundel2);
                startActivity(iinntteen);
            }
        });


        if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_balongdalem"))
         {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_balong);
            nama.setText("Balong Dalem");
            alamat.setText(R.string.add_balong);
            keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_balong);
            iinntteen = new Intent(KetWisata.this, Arahkan.class); 
            tampil2 ="coba";                    //TAMPIL2 CANT DETECTED..
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_curugbangkong"))
         { 
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_bangkong2);
            nama.setText("Curug Bangkong");
            alamat.setText(R.string.add_bangkong);
            keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_bangkong);
            iinntteen = new Intent(KetWisata.this, Tentang.class);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_buperciberem"))
         {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_ciberem2);
            nama.setText("Buper Cibeureum");
            alamat.setText(R.string.add_ciberem);
            keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_ciberem);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_cibulan"))
         {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_cibulan2);
            nama.setText("Kolam Cibulan");
            alamat.setText(R.string.add_cibulan);
            keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_cibulan);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_balongcicerem"))
         { 
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_balong);
            nama.setText("Balong Cicereum");
            alamat.setText(R.string.add_cicerem);
            keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_cicerem);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_balongcigugur"))
         {
             img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_cigugur2);
             nama.setText("Balong Cigugur");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_cigugur);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_cigugur);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_curugcilengkrang"))
         {

                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_cilengkrang2);
                nama.setText("Lembah Cilengkrang");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_cilengkrang);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_cilengkrang);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_cipari"))
         {           
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_cipari2);
                nama.setText("Taman Purbakala Cipari");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_cipari);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_cipari);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_balongdarmaloka"))
         {           
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_darmaloka2);
                nama.setText("Balong Darmaloka");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_darmaloka);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_darmaloka);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_linggarjatiindah"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_linggarjat2i);
                nama.setText("Linggarjati Indah");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_linggarjati);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_linggarjati);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_guamaria"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_guamaria);
                nama.setText("Gua Maria");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_guamaria);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_guamaria);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_gedungnaskah"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_muslinggar2);
                nama.setText("Musium Linggarjati");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_naskah);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_naskah);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_buperpalutungan"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_palutungan2);
                nama.setText("Buper Plautungan");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_palutungan);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_palutungan);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_buperpaniis"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_paniis2);
                nama.setText("Buper Paniis");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_paniis);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_paniis);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_paseban"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_paseban);
                nama.setText("Gedung Merapat Lima");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_paseban);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_paseban);
         }
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_gedungsahrir"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_gedungsut);
                nama.setText("Gedung Sutan Syahrir");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_syahrir);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_syahrir);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_sanggariang"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_sanggariang2);
                nama.setText("Kolam Renang Sanggariang");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_sanggariang);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_sanggariang);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_sangkanurip"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_sangkanurip2);
                nama.setText("Pemandian Sangkanurip");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_sangkanurip);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_sangkanhurip);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_curugsidomba"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_sidomba2);
                nama.setText("Sidomba");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_sidomba);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_sidomba);
         }      
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_talagaremis"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_talagaremis);
                nama.setText("Talagaremis");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_talagaremis);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_talagaremis);        }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_tngc"))
         {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_tngc);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_wadukdarma"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_waduk2);
                nama.setText("Waduk Darma");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_waduk);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_waduk);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_abn"))
         {
            img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_abn);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_hasanmaulana"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_hasanmaulana);
                nama.setText("Gedung Hasan Maulani");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_hasanmaulana);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_hasanmaulana);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_makamvanbeck"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_makamvanbeck);
                nama.setText("Makam Van Beck");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_makamvanbeck);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_makamvanbeck);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_situscangkuang"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_situscangkuang);
                nama.setText("Situs Cangkuang");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_cangkuang);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_cangkuang);
         }       
         if(tampil.equalsIgnoreCase("wis_talaganilem"))
         {
                img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wis_talaganilem);
                nama.setText("Talaganilem");
                alamat.setText(R.string.add_talaganilem);
                keterangan.setText(R.string.ket_talaganilem);
         }

         //arahkan.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        //  @Override
        //  public void onClick(View arg0) {
        //      startActivity(new Intent(KetWisata.this, Arahkan.class));

        //  }
        //});
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: You've provided 238 lines of code, when probably about 10 would have been adequate to show the problem. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 0):

Before doing this line: 
`getIntent().getExtras().ANYTHING_ELSE`
Make sure that:
`getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null` You can also check for `getIntent().getExtras().isEmpty()`